# How can I write a generic function that works for deserializing multiple output types from TOML?

Tags: rust

I wrote a utility method that creates a configuration object from a TOML file:

```
pub fn read_common(path: &str) -> Result<Config> {
    let content = read_file(path);
    toml::from_str(&content?).map_err(|e| {
        Error::new(
            ErrorKind::InvalidData,
            format!(
                "Parsing failed at line {:?}, col {:?}",
                e.line_col().map(|p| p.0),
                e.line_col().map(|p| p.1)
            ),
        )
    })
}
```

`Config` is a simple deserializable struct:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct DatabaseConfig {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: u16,
    pub database: String,
    pub user: String,
    pub password: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Config {
    pub database: DatabaseConfig,
}
```

This compiles and runs fine (as it should, since this is almost copy-pasted from [the toml crate's documentation](https://docs.rs/toml/0.4.8/toml/)).

I have multiple config files with each their corresponding matching struct, so I want to generify my `read_common` method (to reuse the same error handling in all other cases).

I wrote this:

```
pub fn read<'de, T>(path: &str) -> Result<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let content = read_file(path);
    toml::from_str(&content?).map_err(|e| {
        Error::new(
            ErrorKind::InvalidData,
            format!(
                "Parsing failed at line {:?}, col {:?}",
                e.line_col().map(|p| p.0),
                e.line_col().map(|p| p.1)
            ),
        )
    })
}
```

`T` is the type of the configuration produced by the deserialization. I need to have it extend `Deserialize<'..>` so I need to give a lifetime here, but the full signature of `toml::from_str` is

```
pub fn from_str<'de, T>(s: &'de str) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: de::Deserialize<'de>,
```

In my understanding, my input string should have the same (or larger) lifetime than the produced deserialized object. Which of course it hasn't in my implementation since its lifetime ends at the end of my `read` method. The borrow checker thus complains (`borrowed value does not live long enough on &content?`) and this implementation does not compile.

How can I write a generic `read` version of my `read_common` that works for multiple output types?

Additional questions I have about this issue:

- What happens with the lifetimes in `read_common`? The deserialized string is also short lived, how come this implementation compiles? I guess there is some tricks hidden in the `#[derive(Deserialize)]`.
- Why does `toml::from_str` give the same lifetime to its input variable and output type? For me the output should not refer to the input string once deserialization is finished, so why are there lifetimes in the method declaration?

Comment: *the same lifetime to its input variable and output type* — this is the most memory-efficient implementation possible. If you parse the words out of the string `[hello]{world}`, you could allocate new memory to store the words and copy them (`String`) or you could just reference the existing words in place (`&str`).